# "Lowest yield" atomic weapon possible

Tags: nuclear-physics, nuclear-engineering, explosions

I would ask that folks be tolerant of my ignorance in this field. When discussing tactical and strategic nuclear weapon yield I wonder about what is the lowest possible fission weapon is possible. A "dirty bomb" (conventional bomb spreading nuclear contamination) is not the question. I would like education on the topic.

Comment: If you do not care at all about the _efficiency\*_ of the weapon, then I doubt that there is any lower limit to the yield energy. [\* I'm using "efficiency" to mean the ratio of yield energy to the amount of nuclear material used in the construction.]

Comment: Clearly the lowest possible yield is zero. One can design for any yield above that.

Comment: my interpretation of this question is that BradV is asking how much would the *smallest* spontaneously exploding amount of fissionable material be and what would that amount's yield be as a weapon if one could design it with 100% efficiency?

Comment: I don't think fizzles should count, so we're talking a well formed super critical mass. If not: it is two U-235 atoms in quantum Zeno device, preventing decay, with one neutron gun pointing at the "initiator" atom, and the other atom is "the pit".  So the yield is around 400 MeV. or $\frac 1 2 M_P c^2$

Comment: @hyportnex The explosion energy doesn't primarily depend on the amount of material. It depends in a much stronger way on the length of containment that allows the reaction to continue. bringing two critical masses together slowly will result in a very small "explosion" by nuclear standards. The subcritical masses will simply get very hot until the thermal expansion will drive them apart and restore subcriticality. See e.g. the accident of Harry Daghlian in 1945.

Comment: Jon Custer's comment is the answer, I am afraid. The trick they had to learn when making the bomb was the opposite: how to maximize the yield.

Comment: @JonCuster There was a betting pool before the Trinity test to see who could come closest to predicting the actual yield. I think that Fermi would have won the pool if the bomb had ignited the atmosphere and ended all life on Earth. Ramsey would have won the pool if the yield had been zero.

Comment: @Qmechanic what would be the appropriate location at stack exchange to ask this?  My curiosity is spurred by recent Russian sabre rattling over Ukraine. I hope to get a serious and fact based answer to understand how small of yield a tactical nuke might be.

Answer (score 1):

The yield of many weapon designs can be adjusted, typically by changing the firing time of external neutron initiators or the quantity of deuterium-tritium boosting gas injected into the core.

The lowest yield setting on a fielded US nuclear weapon was 10 tons TNT equivalent, on the W54 warhead as used in the Davy Crockett artillery shell and the SADM backpack bomb. In principle they could be reduced lower than that, but I can imagine it being difficult to accurately regulate the yield when it's right at the threshold of a fizzle.

Comment: For comparison, the very largest conventional bombs (such as the GBU-43/B MOAB) have yields from 10 tons TNT equivalent up to about 40 tons TNT equivalent.